# Is this the right way to cast

Tags: android, kotlin, android-adapter, baseadapter

What is the best way to cast an object to a certain type of object if it's not null (otherwise, a factory method is called). This is happening inside a BaseAdapter. What's the best way to do it?

```
val itemView = view as? ItemView ?: factory()
```

I'm getting the following warning in Android Studio

> Unchecked cast: View? to ItemView

Comment: `@Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")` if you know what you are doing ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can handle it elegantly and functionally with pattern matching:

```
val itemView = when(view) {
    is ItemView -> view
    else -> factory()
}
```